# Bug in my shell script after manipulating positional parameters with quotes?

Tags: shell, busybox

Before this point in the script, I used `set -- "$@"` and `shift` to transform the positional arguments for a call to `find`.

Here's an example of the manipulation I did:

```
set -- "$@" -iname "\"*$1\"" -print
```

Below, I echo what I think I'm about to execute. But when I pipe the result to a while loop, it doesn't report any files (vs when I run it manually).

```
set -x
echo find "$@"
find "$@" 2>/dev/null | while read -r f; do
                            echo found "$f"
                        done
```

Here's the output of the script. (Note the double quotes `"` below. Note also a comment below about how my environment (BusyBox v1.18.4) `set -x` isn't displaying quotes properly.)

```
+ echo find /images/dir -follow -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.png" -print -o -iname "*.jpg" -print
find /images/dir -follow -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.png" -print -o -iname "*.jpg" -print
+ read -r f
+ find /images/dir -follow -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.png" -print -o -iname "*.jpg" -print
```

(A non-buggy `set -x` prints out `'"*.png"'` instead of `"*.png"`.)

As you can see, it didn't print out any file names. Here's what happens when I check (what I think is) the same thing at the prompt:

```
$ find /images/dir -follow -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.png" -print -o -iname "*.jpg" -print  2>/dev/null | while read -r f; do
> echo found "$f"
> done
found /images/dir/foo.jpg
found /images/dir/bar.png
```

What is causing the difference? This is on `BusyBox v1.18.4`

Comment: Quotes in your positional argument values are not going to work as you expect. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for discussion of this. The tl;dr version is you don't want the quotes *in* the value the quotes around `"$@"` ensure that each argument is unevaluated and is not word-split.

Comment: BTW, I don't see where you're showing the actual argv-manipulation code responsible for the problem. Please try to show enough code in your questions that folks can copy-and-paste to reproduce the problem.

Comment: (As a separate aside, the busybox shell you're using has a buggy implementation of `set -x` that isn't correctly escaping quotes in its output; *sigh*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is looking for filenames with literal `"` characters in them.

This implies that you're doing something like:

```
set -- "$@" -iname '"*.png"'
```

...instead of the correct alternative...

```
set -- "$@" -iname '*.png'
```

See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for details and background on the set of misunderstandings that generally lead to this bug. :)

Comment: Actually instead of `.png` I had `$1` so the problem was in saying `"\"*$1\""` instead of perhaps `"*$1"` which appears to work. Same idea as your answer and Etan Reisner's comment. I think the accepted answer should link to something like that FAQ/050